# Docker install from file

Tags: docker, grafana

I am wonder if you know how to install a package if there is no Internet connection.
I tried to bridge the connection and somehow pass the Internet but nothing works.
I am trying to install on Docker on Linux a Grafana software (https://grafana.com/) .
I can only connect to Linux by Putty.
I have whole rep from git of "Grafena software" and i really do not know how to install it from local file.
Any ideas?
I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to install the graphana docker image on a machine without internet connection.

Assuming you can download on your own machine, you can do the following:

```sh
docker pull grafana/grafana:7.2.0
docker save -o grafana_img.tar grafana/grafana:7.2.0
# transfer the file on the remote machine using sftp or scp
```

on the remote machine

```sh
docker load -i grafana_img.tar
```

Comment: good :) btw if you start working with big images I suggest to zip (and unzip) the tar file. It might save a lot of time